# what does Jivatma mean

Tags: scripture, shiva, vedanta, sri-vaishnava

Is Shiva jivatma?

Shiva does neither born or die.

In the Vaishnav parampara, it is said that Siva is jivatma.

Could you please illustrate this providing some relevant scripture from reliable source?

Comment: It depends on the particular Sampradaya. Not all Vaishnavas see Shiva as Jiva.

Comment: Jiva means life. We all are jivas. We are amsha of Parabrahman.